# Who was the last college senior (used all four years of college eligibility) to be the first pick in the NBA draft?

Tags: nba, draft

I suppose with a few hours of research I could figure it out…so I’m not asking anyone to go through that. Just wondering if anyone knows the answer or has found a single source of the information. All of the lists I’ve found are lacking it.

Answer (score 1):

[Kenyon Martin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kenyon_Martin) was drafted first overall in the year 2000, after his senior year of college at the University of Cincinnati.  He played [all four years](https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/players/kenyon-martin-1.html), though his first year was not a starting role for the most part (only appearing in 22 games, and starting 3 of them).  No first overall pick after him played all four years of college (or even particularly close to it).